# Hashtag Uniqueness

Tags: java, arraylist, hashtag

I am trying to find unique hashtags from a tweet that a user inputs. My brother was helping me, but he had to leave. Anyway, so i have the code to find the number of times a word is used in the input, but I just need to know the number of different hashtags used. For example, in the input "#one #two blue red #one #green four", there would be 3 unique hashtags as #one, #two, and #green. I cannot figure out how to code this.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Tweet {


public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner hashtag = new Scanner( System.in );
System.out.println( "Please enter a line of text" );
String userInput = hashtag.nextLine();

userInput = userInput.toLowerCase();

userInput = userInput.replaceAll( "\\W", " " );     // strip out any non words.
userInput = userInput.replaceAll( "  ", " " );      // strip out any double spaces
                                                    //   created from stripping out non words
                                                    //   in the first place!
String[] tokens = userInput.split( " " );
System.out.println( userInput );

ArrayList< String > tweet = new ArrayList< String >();

tweet.addAll( Arrays.asList( tokens ) );

int count = 0;

for( int i = 0; i < tweet.size(); i++ )
{
    System.out.printf( "%s: ", tweet.get( i ) );
    for( int j = 0; j < tweet.size(); j++ )
    {
        if( tweet.get( i ).equals( tweet.get( j ) ) )
            count++;
        if( tweet.get( i ).equals( tweet.get( j ) ) && count > 1 )
            tweet.remove( j );                      // after having counted at least
    }                                               // one, remove duplicates from List        
    System.out.printf( "%d\n", count );
    count = 0;
}
```

}
}

Comment: *"My brother was helping me, but he had to leave."* - Why?  Tell us more about your brother. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here's some working code you can use.

I removed your string replacements because I'm not sure why you'd want to remove non-word characters -- you'd be removing the '#' on your hashtags. And multiple spaces are not a problem -- split() will just turn them into harmless empty strings.

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;

public class HashTags {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a line of text");
        String tweet = scanner.nextLine();
        Set<String> hashtags = getHashtags(tweet);      
        System.out.println(hashtags.toString());
    }

    public static Set<String> getHashtags(String tweet) {
        String[] words = tweet.split(" ");
        Set<String> hashtags = new HashSet<String>();
        for (String word : words) {
            if (word.startsWith("#")) {
                hashtags.add(word);
            }
        }
        return hashtags;
    }
}
```

Here's the output for a sample run:

> ```
> Please enter a line of text
> #one #two blue red #one #green four     #jaja hg
> [#one, #two, #jaja, #green]
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Use a HashSet like in the example below:

```
HashSet<String> hashTags = new HashSet<String>();
if(word.startsWith("#") && !hashTags.contains(word)){
  hashTag.add(word);
}
```

After you have processed the tweet `hashTags` will contain all the unique hash tags you saw. You can iterate over it to get them.